# Angular2 - Extending router and Observable

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, angular, angular2-router

In angular2 rc2 with the router module v 3.0.0.6alpha, I extend the RouterOulet to check if the user is logged in before accessing the admin. So this is the code :

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet 
{
    publicRoutes: Array<string>;
    private parentOutletMap: RouterOutletMap;
    private userService: UserService;
    private parentRouter: Router;

    constructor(
        parentOutletMap: RouterOutletMap,
        _location: ViewContainerRef,
        @Attribute('name') name: string,
        userService: UserService,
        parentRouter: Router
    ) { 
        super(parentOutletMap, _location, name);

        this.parentRouter = parentRouter;
        this.parentOutletMap = parentOutletMap;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.publicRoutes = [
            'public', 
            'login'
        ];
    }

    activate(factory: ComponentFactory<any>, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, providers: ResolvedReflectiveProvider[], outletMap: RouterOutletMap) 
    {
        if (this._canActivate(factory.selector)) { 
            return super.activate(factory, activatedRoute, providers, outletMap); 
        }

        this.parentRouter.navigate(['/login']);
    }

    _canActivate(url) {
        return this.publicRoutes.indexOf(url) !== -1 || this.userService.isLoggedIn()
    }
}
```

userService.isLoggedIn() has to return a boolean. My question is : How do I adapt my code to make an http call to check if the user is logged in ? Because if the isLoggedIn method return an observable object, and I subscribe it, I can't return the result in the parent function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please notice that the result of activate method of OutletRouter has changed.

**@angular/router-deprecated**

`activate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction) : Promise<any>`

**@angular/router**

`activate(factory: ComponentFactory<any>, providers: ResolvedReflectiveProvider[], outletMap: RouterOutletMap) : ComponentRef<any>`

which is not a Promise or Observable any more. New router implementation comes with a bit different solution that I think is cleaner: Guards.

> A guard's return value controls the router's behavior:
>
> if it returns true, the navigation process continues if it returns
>   false, the navigation process stops and the user stays put The guard
>   can also tell the router to navigate elsewhere, effectively canceling
>   the current navigation.
>
> The guard might return its boolean answer synchronously. But in many
>   cases, the guard can't produce an answer synchronously. The guard
>   could ask the user a question, save changes to the server, or fetch
>   fresh data. These are all asynchronous operations.
>
> Accordingly, a routing guard can return an Observable and the
>   router will wait for the observable to resolve to true or `false.

You can create auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable }             from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate,
         Router,
         ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
         RouterStateSnapshot }    from '@angular/router';
import { UserService }            from './user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    // Not using but worth knowing about
    next:  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    return this.userService.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

Now make sure your isLoggedIn return Observable (or Promise - try both as Angular2 Reference is [not ready yet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html)). In my case API returns JSON in format: { success: true / false }.

```
public isLoggedIn() : Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    let router: Router = this.router;
    let obs;

    try {
        obs = this.authHttp.get('/api/check/logged')
            .map(result => result.json())
            .map(resultJson => (resultJson && resultJson.success));

    } catch (err) {
        obs = Observable.of(false);
    }

    return obs
        .map(success => {
             // navigate to login page
             if (!success)
                 router.navigate(['/auth/login']);

             return success;
        });
}
```

Then just modify your RouterConfig array:

```
{ path: '/secret', component: SercetComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

Refer also to [Angular2 Developer Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: Seems good, thanks ! But I wonder where to inject that guard ? If you can edit your code to show it...

Comment: I did few minutes after posting original answer ;) I forgot to add this before.

Comment: Neat ! Thanks again

Comment: I implemented the code and get "No provider for AuthGuard", yet I added it to my main component provider. Do you know why ?

Comment: Try to add to your route.ts: 
export const AUTH_PROVIDERS = [AuthGuard, UserService];
and then add it in your bootstrap global providers.

Comment: I'm using rc2 and I don't see CanActivate from @angular/router.  Isn't CanActivate from router-deprecated?

Comment: Nope. You probably don't have right router package (it's not in 2.0.0-rc.2). Add to your dependencies in package.json: "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-alpha.3" and update. You should get it :)

Comment: @baumi You're right.  I thought angular rc2 would get me that right router with everything at version 2.  Apparently I was wrong.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The last version is 3.0.0-alpha.7 now.Thanks for the hint @Baumi I got everything to work now

Comment: @Baumi Do you mind taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897273/authguard-doesnt-wait-for-authentication-to-finish-before-checking-user ? I guess I got the concept, but I've no idea how to turn angularfire's auth into an Observable<boolean>. Basically I don't know what should my authservice return. Thanks!

Comment: How to redirect to the login page, if an Observable is return false ?

Comment: @Baumi, what is authservice? it is never defined

Comment: @JamesFreund - it should be userService that is injected in constructor. Thanks for pointing that out.