# AuthGuard doesn't wait for authentication to finish before checking user

Tags: angular, angularfire

I've read the guide here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Seems pretty straightforward, however, I'm not sure how to use angularfire2's authentication within an auth guard (`canActivate`). What I've tried is:

**AuthService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private user: any;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    })
  }

  get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.user ? true : false;
  }

}
```

**AuthGuard**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.authenticated)
      return true;

    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  } 

}
```

I've also added *AuthService* to bootstrap providers.

This sort of works fine, however, my main problem is when I refresh (or initially load) the page on that has `AuthGuard` it always redirects me to the login page since the `AuthGuard` doesn't wait for the authentication response. Is there a way to wait for the authentication to finish (even if it's failed) and *then* check whether the user is authenticated?

Comment: See this answer, it has implemented auth guard properly http://stackoverflow.com/a/37889258/652850

Comment: Doesn't really solve my problem with angularfire2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is with your code. In the AuthGuard you check the result of authenticated() method that will most probably return false as the user property is still not set. Try this:

**AuthService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private user: any;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }
  setUser(user) { this.user = user; }
  getAuthenticated(): Observable<any> { return this.af.auth; }
}
```

**AuthGuard**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    // here check if this is first time call. If not return 
    // simple boolean based on user object from authService
    // otherwise:

    return this.authService.getAuthenticated.map(user => {
          this.authService.setUser(user);
          return user ? true : false;
    })

  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to modify this so that I get the user data in the AuthService constructor? With the way you solved it I don't get the user data only on guarded routes, but, for example, I have a header which would show the user's email address on non-guarded routes as well.

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to work, since the `canActivate()` method has to return `Observable<boolean> | boolean`, but in your example it doesn't return anything. How can I solve that?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to return a result in canActivate.

Comment: How to redirect to the login page, if an Observable is return false ?

Comment: @EfriandikaPratama this.router.navigate(['login']);

Comment: This also seems to delegate the authentication to the guard.  Although the actual call definition for authentication has be delegated back to the AuthService, you are setting the user in the guard.  Other guards would have to also implement this same logic.

Answer (score 9):

It may be different in some versions of the router but I needed to return an observable that **completes**.

```
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router'

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.af.auth.map(user => {
      if (user != null)
        return true
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    })
    .take(1) // To make the observable complete after the first emission
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2021 UPDATE for AngularFire, RXJS and Firebase

Taken from [Baumi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905166)

```
**AuthService**:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private user: firebase.default.User;

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFire) { }

    setUser(user) { 
        this.user = user; 
    }
    
    getAuthenticated(): Observable<firebase.default.User> { 
        return this.afAuth.user; 
        }
}


**AuthGuard**:
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private router: Router, 
        private authService: AuthService
    ) {}

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        // here check if this is first time call. If not return 
        // simple boolean based on user object from authService
        // otherwise:

        return this.authService.getAuthenticated().pipe(
            map(user => {
                this.authService.setUser(user);
                return user ? true : false;
            })
        )
    } 
}
```