# angular2 canActivate() not work with Observable response

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

i have problem with canActivate angular2.0.0-rc.3.

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>{
    console.log('canActivate with AclService'); 
   // return true;
    return Observable.create((observer:Subject<boolean>) => { observer.next(true);  });
   }
```

it's not work with Observable response but work with simple boolean response.

how can i fix this problem ??

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? What do you expect? What is happening?

Comment: not working mean canActivate role is not working : if i return boolean ( true or false ) it's work mean if true aceess to current route is permit or not if return false , but if return Observable<boolean> it's not work

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I followed answer from question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897273/authguard-doesnt-wait-for-authentication-to-finish-before-checking-user but It doesn't work. When I call `return true;` immediately, it works.

Comment: @DarwinGautalius i add the same issue to github angular project https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9613

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you add `.first()` or complete the `Observable` by other means it should work:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>{
    console.log('canActivate with AclService'); 
   // return true;
    return Observable.create((observer:Subject<boolean>) => { observer.next(true);  }).first();
}
```

or

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>{
    console.log('canActivate with AclService'); 
   // return true;
    return Observable.of(true);
}
```

Comment: ...and what if I want an Http call the result of which means canActivate = false?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the question is about.