# Angular2+ redirectTo not working when redirect to a link with canActivate

Tags: angular, typescript, router

The `redirectTo` failed to redirect to a link with `canActivate` when I logged in
.

The `redirectTo` works fine when I logged out, it redirectTo my `/login` component and `redirectTo` to `/index` after logged in.

But it stick on `''` when I'm logged In.

I had add `console.log` to my `authGuard`, and the redirect url "/index" did go in that function at the stick to `''` situation with no crash in development tool.

But after comment the `canActivate`, the `redirectTo` work fine like before.

By the way, my authGuard with `canActivate` work fine in other situations(exclude `redirecTo`)

Here's my app-routing.module.ts

```
/* import... */

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo : '/index', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

/* ngmodel and export ... */
```

and here's my index-routing.module.ts

```
/* import ... */

const indexRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'index',
        component: IndexComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard], //<- if comment this will work
    },
];

/*   ngmodel and export ... */
```

here's my auth-guard.module.ts

```
/* import ... */

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url;
        //redirectTo did get in here
        console.log(url); //<-- this show /index 

        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.authService.login_data && (this.authService.login_data.userprofile || !this.authService.login_data.need_login)) {
            return true;
        }
        this.authService.get_login_data()
         .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.authService.login_data = data;
                if (data.userprofile || !data.need_login) {
                    return true;
                }
                this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return false;
            },
            error => { this.authService.errMsg = <any>error;}
        );
    }
}
```

By the way I had updated my project to angular4.0.1

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I've changed my guard return from boolean to Observable

but it still doesn't work.

here's the code I had used.

```
    checkLogin(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
        if (this.authService.login_data && (this.authService.login_data.userprofile || !this.authService.login_data.need_login)) {
            console.log('gonna return observable true');
            return Observable.of(true);
            //return true;
        }
        this.authService.get_login_data()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.authService.login_data = data;
                if (data.userprofile || !data.need_login) {
                    console.log('in subscribe and gonna return observable true');
                    return Observable.of(true);
                    //return true;
                }
                this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return Observable.of(false);
                //return false;
            },
            error => { this.authService.errMsg = <any>error;}
        );
    }
```

In my console, I got `in subscribe and gonna return observable true`

**UPDATE:**

after check after checking this

[AuthGuard doesn't wait for authentication to finish before checking user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897273/authguard-doesnt-wait-for-authentication-to-finish-before-checking-user)

the problem may be that `canActivate` doesn't wait the subscribe end.

Comment: This my first question. I will make it better after reading. Thanks.

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: no error, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `checkLogin()` of `AuthGuard`:

```
checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.authService.login_data && (this.authService.login_data.userprofile || !this.authService.login_data.need_login)) {
        return true;
    }
    this.authService.get_login_data()
     .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.authService.login_data = data;
            if (data.userprofile || !data.need_login) {
                return true;
            }
            this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        },
        error => { this.authService.errMsg = <any>error;}
    );
}
```

it's return type is boolean, it return true, in some condition, it is ok. But, the later part has some problem. You didn't return anything, until you subscribe the result and return based on that result.

It means, this function will return undefined,  so the canActivate check will not work.

[Updated] You want to set user data from the result, you should use `do()` in your `authService.get_login_data()` to set it. When you subscribe the result, this 'do' function will be called. And in your `checkLogin()` use `.map()` instead of `subscribe()` to map the login result data to boolean.

In this situation, you should return a Observable type, like:

```
checkLogin(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
if (this.authService.login_data && (this.authService.login_data.userprofile || !this.authService.login_data.need_login)) {
    return Observable.of(true); // wrap true in Observable
}
return this.authService.get_login_data()
 .map(
    data => {
        if (data.userprofile || !data.need_login) {
            return true;
        }
        this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    },
    error => { this.authService.errMsg = <any>error;}
);
```

}

Comment: `.subscribe()` does not return an `Observable`. It returns a `Subscription`, which is of course the real problem here.

Comment: I changed code make it return Observable(true); but it still doesn't work. If the subscribe is the problem, any idea to make sure I can check login situation after data back from server?

Comment: sorry, I had a mistake, you want to return true/false based on the result. You should use `.map`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by changing subscribe to map.

[Angular2 canActivate() calling async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425461/angular2-canactivate-calling-async-function)

here's my code after edited.

```
checkLogin(url: string): Observable<boolean>|boolean {
    if (this.authService.login_data && (this.authService.login_data.userprofile || !this.authService.login_data.need_login)) {
        console.log('gonna return observable true');
        return Observable.of(true);
    }   
    return this.authService.get_login_data()
    .map(
        data => {
            this.authService.login_data = data;
            if (data.userprofile || !data.need_login) {
                console.log('in subscribe and gonna return observable true');
                //return Observable.of(true);
                return true;                                                                                                                                                
            }   
            this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            //return Observable.of(false);
            return false;
        },  
        error => { this.authService.errMsg = <any>error;}
    );  
}
```

in the map i got error if i return Observable(true)

`Type 'Observable<Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<boolean>'.`

Thanks for help and suggestions.